# I need help knowing where to start on designing a tableview or if a tableview is what I need

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: The table view I believe holds the game info, images and holds buttons.]

As in title, I don't know where to start with creating a view like this. Do I hard code it or use XCode editor? Is a table view what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `UITableView` is what you needed.

1. You need to create a TableView Controller.

[image]

2. Follow by creating a `TableViewCell`
   [image]

Then you need to start coding. Hook up the delegate and data source methods.
For more information, check this tutorial by Apple: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any more questions, and I'll be happy to answer them. If you find my answer is helpful, would you like to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a tableView with section header indicating the date of the matches, the tableView has a custom designed cell, each cell contains the names of the two competing team.

- start by adding the tableView to your viewController using storyboards, with the delegate and datasource connected.
- the sub class from UITableViewCell and create your custom cell with an xib file.